# bot stops working on changing tf listener 'target_frame' to '/odom', works fine for other frames

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-melodic, tf2, transform-listener

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a simple P controller in the callback of my 'scan_subscriber' Subscriber. It is working as intended.

I also wanted to transform the laser scan data from '/base_laser' frame to '/odom' frame.

So, I wrote a simple transform listener inside '**tf_callback**' function, setting the **target_frame** as **'/odom'**. This makes the bot to not work as intended (It moves for a while and then topples).

However, when I change the target_frame to **any frame other than '/odom'**, the bot works just fine.

How can 'listener.waitForTransform' or 'listener.transformPoint' functions interfere with the publising of another topic ('/cmd_vel') ?

What am I missing? I have been trying to debug this for 2 days now.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
import math
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped,  Point, Twist
import tf
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker 

class HuskyBot: 

    def __init__(self): 

        
        rospy.init_node('husky_node')
            
        self.laser_point = Point(0,0,0) 

        self.scan_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, self.laser_callback)
        
        self.tf_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('/scan' , LaserScan, self.tf_callback)

        self.velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel' , Twist, queue_size = 1000) 

        self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)

        rospy.spin()
                

    def tf_callback(self, data): 
    
                


        laser_point_stamped  = PointStamped() 

        laser_point_stamped.header.frame_id = "/base_laser"
        laser_point_stamped.header.stamp = rospy.Time() 

        laser_point_stamped.point = self.laser_point 
        
        listener = tf.TransformListener()

        try: 
            
            last_time = rospy.Time.now() 
            

            ''' Program runs successfully on changing the target frame to any frame other than odom '''

            target_frame = '/odom'

            listener.waitForTransform(target_frame , '/base_laser' , rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
               
            
            odom_point = listener.transformPoint(target_frame , laser_point_stamped)
       

        except Exception as e: 

            print "Following exception was enconuntered while performing the transformation -> " + str(e)


    def laser_callback(self, data): 
        

        pillar_dis = 100000  

        pos = 0 

         
        for idx, val in enumerate(data.ranges) : 

            if not math.isinf(val): 

                if val  < pillar_dis : 
                    
                    pillar_dis = val 

                    pos = idx 

        pillar_ang  = data.angle_min + pos * data.angle_increment 


        vel_msg = Twist() 

        tolerance = 0.1 
        
        ''' Simple P controller to navigate the bot ''' 

        if pillar_dis > tolerance : 

            v_x = 1.5 * pillar_dis 

            w_z = 4 * (0 - pillar_ang) 

            vel_msg.linear.x = v_x 
            vel_msg.angular.z  = w_z 

            self.velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg) 
        

        p_x = pillar_dis * math.cos(pillar_ang) 
        p_y = pillar_dis * math.sin(pillar_ang) 
        p_z = 0 

        self.laser_point = Point(p_x, p_y, p_z) 


if __name__ == '__main__' : 

    x = HuskyBot()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364804/bot-stops-working-on-changing-tf-listener-%27target_frame%27-to-%27/odom%27,-works-fine-for-other-frames/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2020-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-11-05**:
It looks like `odom_point` is not used after it's assigned, is that correct? Are there any errors or warnings in the logs?  Is there anything suspicious in your tf tree (multiple publishers of the same transform, slow rates, etc.)?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-05**:
Can you please explain why you have two subscribers to the `/scan` topic, one called "scan_subscriber" and the other called "tf_subscriber"? Also what is the output of `rosrun tf view_frames`? Is your tf tree built as you expect? (read: does it follow [REP105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)?)

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-05**:
@tryan

The plan was to use publish visualisation_markers using `odom_point`. But I removed that to resolve the above mentioned error first.

Also, it seems like there is an issue with the line `listener.waitForTransform(target_frame , '/base_laser' , rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(1.0))`.

Once I comment out this line, and keep  `odom_point = listener.transformPoint(target_frame , laser_point_stamped)`, the bot runs just fine, but I receive this exception - `Following exception was enconuntered while performing the transformation -> "odom" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist`.

How can the  `listener.waitForTransform(target_frame , '/base_laser' , rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(1.0))`.  interfere with the topic '/cmd_vel'?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-05**:
@skpro19 are you 100% sure the odom frame exists?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-05**:
@JackB

[This](https://ibb.co/MB1w1c3) is how my frames.pdf look like. Since, I am using a standard husky_bot, I don't think there should be an issue with REP105 compliance.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-05**:
@JackB There is no particular reason. I was first trying to achieve the things mentioned in the 'tf_callback' function inside the 'laser_callback' function itself. But. since I was facing the above mentioned error, I thought of making 2 different subscribers.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-05**:
You should try to avoid making two subscribers like that once you have the problem figured out, but I understand.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-11-05**:
@skpro19 While this may not be the actual problem, it will help clarify things if you recombine the callbacks and move the listener constructor into the `__init__` function as @JackB suggested.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-05**:
Thanks @tryan, I was able to resolve the issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the first part of Tom Moore's answer to this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/192570/tftransformlistenertransformpose-exception-target_frame-does-not-exist/).

You are making the tf listener in the callback, which executes SO fast, that the system doesn't have time to register it. Make the tf listener a class variable just like you do with the publishers and subscribers and test it again.

Without looking too much closer, this wouldn't exactly explain why it works with other setups but not when you set the frame to "/odom", except maybe that non-static tfs  (like odom) take longer to subscribe to. But I think this is a good first step at least to debugging, if this doesn't solve the entire problem.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-05**:
@JackB If we see the tf_tree [image](https://ibb.co/MB1w1c3), we can see that  **odom -> base_link** transform (published by '/**ekf_localization**') has a **50Hz** frequency while all the other transforms between **base_link and its children** (published by '/**robot_state_publisher**') have a **1000Hz** frequency.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-05**:
@skpro19 I am not sure what this comment means with respect to my answer. It confirms what I said about that the non-static tf gets published much much slower than the static tfs (not that we are sure that that is the important part). No matter what you do, remove the `listener = tf.TransformListener()` from the callback function and make it like `self.listener = tf.TransformListener()`.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-05**:
Thank you @JackB for poinitng me in the right direction. I was able to resolve the issue. :-)

I was stuck on this issue for quite some time now. I really appreciate it.

---

I made the following changes to my code -

---

- Added `self.listener =    tf.TransformListener()` and    `self.listener.waitForTransform(target_frame    , '/base_laser' , rospy.Time(),    rospy.Duration(1.0))` inside the    `__init__` function
- Removed `listener =    tf.TransformListener()` and `listener.waitForTransform(target_frame    , '/base_laser' , rospy.Time(),    rospy.Duration(1.0))` from the `tf_callback` function
- Changed `odom_point = listener.transformPoint(target_frame , laser_point_stamped)`
  to `odom_point = self.listener.transformPoint(target_frame , laser_point_stamped)`

---

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-05**:
@skpro19 I am so happy I could help! You can accept my answer as correct or post your own with an explanation and revised code, cheers.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-07**:
@JackB You mentioned - 'You are making the tf listener in the callback, which executes SO fast, that the system doesn't have time to register it. Make the tf listener a class variable just like you do with the publishers and subscribers and test it again.'

Are you saying that the callbacks are being called with such a high frequency that the system doesn't have the time to register the `listener = tf.TransformListener()` ? i.e another callback is called even before the the first callback hasn't been processed completely?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-11-07**:
@skpro19 unless you are using multiple threads, only one callback can ever be processed at a time, and therefore you cannot have another callback executed before the first process exits. That being said I am not 100% sure how the system handles the "registration" of the tf.transfromListener() but it is apparent that what ever happens it doesn't happen fast enough

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2020-11-11**:
@JackB okay.